# How to run a python script by double clicking?

Tags: python, user-interface

I have started learning programming a few days ago and I made my first script which is a simple geography test.You type 't' in front of the true sentence and 'f' in front of the false, and it displays a message and counts marks.
So what I want to do is to run it by double clicking in the command line or in a GUI,
currently when I double click it it shows the first question in the black window and once i give it the first answer 't' r 'f' and press enter it disappeared.
The input() trick to keep the command line open doesn't seem to work here.
And GUI building using tkinter seems too complicated for me now.
So is there a simple way to run this script by double clicking?

This is a sample of my code:

```
q1=input ('Extensive farming depends on huge capital :')

if q1 in['T', 't']:

        print (' Well done :')

else:

        print( 'Oh noooo!')


q2= input ( ' Sudan is famous for producing chewing gum:  ')

if q2 in ['F' , 'f']:

        print ('Well done!')

else:

        print ('Oh Nooooooooo!')
```

Comment: Make it an executable?

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the `argparse` in standard library ( google it ). That will help you to adjust your user interface nicely.

To make it executable - if you are in Gnu/Linux, you can use shebang character(`#!/usr/bin/python`) as first line of your python code. If you are in Windows, I think you can assign the file to execute using python executable.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

> it shows the first question in the black window and once i give it the
>   first answer 't' r 'f' and press enter it disappeared.

The reason its doing this is because you have an error in your script; the script will immediately exit after printing the error message.

The error most probably is because you are using Python 2, where you should be using `raw_input()`, which returns the captured input as a string.

In Python3 `input()` does the same thing. However, in Python 2, `input()` evaluates what you enter on the prompt.